# Can I place a sentence between em-dashes? Do I put a period?

Tags: punctuation

Can I place a sentence between em-dashes? If I can, should I put a period, or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can place a sentence between em dashes—people do it all the time—but you shouldn't put a period after it.

Comment: No spaces before and after em-dashes?

Comment: It depends. See Wikipedia—http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_dash#Em_dash.

Comment: A single sentence would be fine. Multiple sentences can make interpretation confusing, e.g. "He knew — she knew that he knew — that." is fine, but "He knew — he'd long suspected. Now he knew — that." looks like two separate sentences at first.